# Proving $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt$ for all x

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, proof-verification

Suppose f has a continuous second derivative. Prove $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt$ for all x.

Can someone check this for me?

What I started with is that if we let $h(x) = \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt$, then $h'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt) = \frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^x xf''(t) dt) - \frac{d}{dx}(\int_0^x tf''(t) dt)= xf''(x) - xf''(x) = 0$.

We also have $h(x) = \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt = \int_0^x xf''(t) dt - \int_0^x tf''(t) dt = xf'(x) - xf'(0) - \int_0^x tf''(t) dt$ by using the fundamental theorems of calculus.

Then by the product rule and differentiating the integral, $h'(x) = xf''(x) + f'(x)-f'(0) - xf''(x) = f'(x) -f'(0)$. But from the first part, $h'(x) = 0$ so $h'(x) = f'(x) -f'(0) = 0$, so $f'(x) = f'(0)$.

Assuming I applied the fundamental theorems correctly, I let $g(x) = f'(0)x + \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt$. Then $g'(x)= f'(0) +0$. Now we have that $g'(x)=f'(0) = f'(x)$ which implies that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ differ by a constant, so $f(x) = g(x) + c$ = $f'(0)x + \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt + c$.

For x = 0 , $f(0) = f'(0)(0) + \int_0^0 (0-t) f''(t) dt + c$, therefore $c=f(0)$, and therefore $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \int_0^x (x-t) f''(t) dt$ .

Is this correct?

Comment: Your calculation of $h'(x)$ is off, notice that you get $f'(x) = f'(0) \implies f(x) = f'(0) x$

Answer (score 2):

As Jeb noted, the first calculation of $h'(x)$ is incorrect; in fact it contradicts later calculation of the same quantity. Otherwise, the approach is sound, but inefficient. Differentiating integrals with respect to a parameter is an error-prone procedure.  I would do  the following:

In the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt $$
integrate by parts: 
$$\begin{split}
\dots &=  f(0) + (t-x)f'(t)\bigg|_{t=0 }^{t=x} - \int_0^x (t-x)f''(t)\,dt
\\&=  f(0) + x f'(0) +  \int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)\,dt \end{split}$$

Comment: And continue to get Taylor's series.

Comment: Not sure if this comment will get noticed, but I am not following the integration by parts. Could you elaborate?